# Make AWS listening for SpringBoot app on 80 port

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat, amazon-ec2, proxy, reverse-proxy

I have created a `Spring Boot` application which by default is working on `8080 port`. In my `AWS EC2` dashboard  called `security groups` I set: 
[image]

And when I run from command my app which is already one the server I have to provide a `url` like: `blablab.compute.amazonaws.com:8080` -> so I have to provide port on which app is running. How to set `AWS` settings to not providing `port` in the end and that my app will work properly?

Comment: Which J2EE container you are using or is it embedded tomcat?

Comment: It is `Spring Boot` so `Tomcat` is embedded

Answer (score 1):

Couple possible solutions.

1) Use a load balancer in front of your server, and set that so the load balancer listens on port 80 and forwards the requests to port 8080 of the server.

2) Use iptables on the server and have it forward port 80 to port 8080.  Something like:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

Comment: But after that will I have to add ‘:80’ to the url? The case is that I don’t want to add any port number after url

Comment: Nope, no :80 needed.   80 is the standard port that is used for any website request.  Just like you don't need to put in http://stackoverflow.com:80 to get to this site, you would not need to put in :80 on your site either.

Comment: I did but when I try to run `app` I get error which indicates that something is running on `port 8080` - this is Tomcat - `Description:

The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 8080 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured.

Action:

Verify the connector's configuration, identify and stop any process that's listening on port 8080, or configure this application to listen on another port.`

Comment: Hmm, are you sure that another instance of your tomcat app isn't  already running?  If you went the iptables route, can you list out your rules:   iptables -L and iptables -t nat -L

Answer (score 0):

You could actually go to your aws console.

Console-->Configuration(on the left pane)-->Click Edit button against the Software card-->scroll all the way down to Environment properties-->And add the below under name and value respectively:

SERVER_PORT   ||    8080

Finally, click on apply.

And voila!!
You are good to go now.[image: Reference to AWS Console Page]